# Upgrade to Precise leaving system unbootable

Tags: 12.04, boot, partitioning, mount, boot-failure

I've upgraded our server's system from Lucid to Precise and as far as I can tell, it left the system in an un-bootable state. I've read many responses in different threads but my problem has a twist.

When we boot the server, it says

> **The disc drive for / is not ready yet or not present Continue to wait;
>   or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery**

but when I press any of those buttons, it doesn't do anything. I can't boot to any recovery console, and as it is a server and I'm accessing it via iDRAC, there's not much I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this concerning my laptop after I put Precise on there.  I'm not sure if it's the same for servers, but have you tried downloading and running Boot-Repair?  Here is a link to the article that I use: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

It might be getting a disk error of some sort and mounting the root partition as read only, or not at all.  You could check /etc/fstab to see how the filesystem is being mounted, but it seems you are going to have to boot off some other media first.